# install Mod_security on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (Apache, EC2)

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-security

### I get dependency issues when I try to install mode_security on Elastic Beanstalk.

It's pretty simple to recreate it:

**- launch a new PHP environment:**

1. get on the [elastic beanstalk console](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?) and create a new environment (you can register for free)
2. choose 'web server', then 'PHP', then 'load balancing'
3. in 'Application Version' click Next, 'Environment Information' set name and Next
4. in 'Additional Resources','Configuration Details',etc let default then next and launch your environment

**- SSH into your instance:**

If you have the [elastic beanstalk cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html)

1. cd your folder
2. eb use [your env name]
3. eb ssh (you may be asked some confirmations)
4. try to install mod_security: `yum install mod_security`

Now you should have:

```
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.31-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
```

[image]

**Thank you for helping! If you have any questions, I'm here!**

---

I saw on stackoverflow a solution was to remove them `yum remove httpd httpd-tools` and install mod_security, but that brings other dependency issues...

Comment: Do `yum search mod_security` and see if there's a `mod_security24` or something similar.

Comment: @ceejayoz, i get:

`mod_security_crs-extras.noarch : Supplementary mod_security rules
mod_security.x86_64 : Security module for the Apache HTTP Server
mod_security_crs.noarch : ModSecurity Rules`

this is the configuration I get at the point I'am when I try to install mod_security without removing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are logged in to your instance (eb or ssh), use this to install the relevant packages:

```
sudo yum install httpd24-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install mod24_security.x86_64
```

Don't forget to restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: Nice one @Dekel ! Do you know what is httpd devel for? it Seems to work without as well

Comment: The package mod_security requires apsx and some other stuff that comes with httpd devel. Probably when you use yum install and give him the correct package, yum will take care of that for you and just install the relevant httpd devel package.